# AlphaVantage API call returns error "Invalid API call"

Tags: python, python-requests, alpha-vantage

I was playing with the alphavantage API and was successfully able to receive the response for BTC to USD exchange rate.

```
{
            'Realtime Currency Exchange Rate': {
                '1. From_Currency Code': 'BTC',
                '2. From_Currency Name': 'Bitcoin',
                '3. To_Currency Code': 'USD',
                '4. To_Currency Name': 'United States Dollar',
                '5. Exchange Rate': '35172.07000000',
                '6. Last Refreshed': '2022-01-22 16:39:01',
                '7. Time Zone': 'UTC',
                '8. Bid Price': '35172.06000000',
                '9. Ask Price': '35172.07000000'
            }
        }
```

However, when I swap the currency, I mean convert USD to BTC, I get Invalid API call.

Below is what I'm trying to do

```
url = https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE&from_currency=USD&to_currency=BTC&apikey=my_api_key`

r = requests.get(url)
```

`{'Error Message': 'Invalid API call. Please retry or visit the documentation (https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/) for CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE.'}`

I visited the document multiple times to confirm if I'm missing anything else but no luck. As per my understanding, the API call structure is exactly the same (including parameters) for either way of currency. So I'm really lost here and really don't have any idea what is wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a bug in their API. It's able to convert currencies from physical->physical, digital->digital and digital->physical but not from physical->digital.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in their API but there is an easy workaround - simply reverse the currencies to get the exchange rate and calculate the reverse exchange rate. here is how I did it

```html
if curr1 in physical_currency_list and curr2 in digital_currency_list:
            temp = curr1
            curr1 = curr2
            curr2 = temp
            bug = True
            
# get rate via requests

if bug == True:

            new_amount =  (1/float(rate)) *float(amount)   #reverse exchange rate
```

Comment: You don't need a temp variable here `x,y=y,x` will work. Also you won't be able to get the lists if the API doesn't allow it, even so it's 3 calls instead of 1.

Comment: @OzgurO. yes true regarding temp. However, please only comment if you actually know the API.  The lists of currencies they support are available as csvs on their webpage. So you simply check whether the user wants to convert a physical to digital currency which triggers the bug. I deployed a currency converter chatbot that uses this API and it all works fine. also not sure what you mean by "3 calls instead of 1"